# Showing no solution exists for small system of multivariate quadratics over a finite field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, finite-fields

I would like to show for the system of polynomials
$$
f_j(\vec{a})=\sum_{i=1}^8 a_i a_{i+j \pmod{8}} = 0, \quad j=1,2,3,4
$$

with $a_i \in \{-1,+1\}$, no common solution can exist. It is easy to confirm this by straightforward brute force calculation of all possible variable combinations.

I would like to find some clearer argument however that does not rely on computational methods, something I think ought to be possible given the highly structured nature of the problem. It is possible to find a common solution for any three out of four polynomials as in $\vec{a} = \{1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1\}$ which is a root for all except when $j=4$ but I can only show this in the specific instance and generalizing the inconsistency has proven difficult.

Is there a way to show this inconsistency directly from the above system of equations? The best approach I can see is via Hilbert's Nullstellenstatz which would entail finding a set of any polynomials $q_j(\vec{a})$ such that
$$
\sum_{j=1}^4 q_j(\vec{a})f_j(\vec{a}) = 1.
$$
I have been quite unsuccessful in this however - such a set of $q_j(\vec{a})$ certainly exist given the iff criteria of the theorem but they may be very complicated. The nice behavior of the $f_j(\vec{a})$ lead me to believe they may be quite nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I might try the following approach.

Let's denote
$$
\Theta(j):=\sum_{i=1}^8a_ia_{i+j}
$$
with index arithmetic done modulo $8$ everywhere. As $a_i\in\{\pm1\}$ for all $i$, we clearly have $\Theta(0)=8$. Also, the obvious symmetry says that $\Theta(j)=\Theta(8-j)$ for $j=1,2,3,4$.

Write
$$
S=a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_8.
$$
If $\Theta(j)=0$ whenever $j=1,2,3,4$, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
S^2&=\sum_{i=1}^8\sum_{j=1}^8a_ia_j\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^8\sum_{\ell=0}^7a_ia_{i+\ell}\\
&=\sum_{\ell=0}^7\Theta(\ell)\\
&=\Theta(0)+2\Theta(1)+2\Theta(2)+2\Theta(3)+\Theta(4)\\
&=\Theta(0)=8.
\end{aligned}
$$
But $S$ is an integer and $8$ is not a perfect square, so this is a contradiction.

Comment: With the OP's example sequence we have $S=4$, $\Theta(0)=8=\Theta(4)$ and the rest of the $\Theta$'s vanish. This matches with the identity.

Comment: Very nice technique, thank you. It seems this argument holds in general for sequences of arbitrary length, excepting those of squared integers where there is no longer a contradiction. In this case one do you think one could consider a higher power of $S$, say $S^4$, and then show that the resulting sum gives one something other than $\Theta(0)^2$?

Comment: Not sure @User71942. After all with length $4$ we have $(1,1,1,-1)$ as a solution! I'm fairly sure some coding theorists have looked at this problem, and more is known. You see, this kind of problems are encountered frequently when designing signal sequences $(a_i)$ for the purposes of getting a time-synch. I dabbled with related questions myself 25 years ago, but mostly looked at sequences $\pm1$s of lengths $2^m-1$ because those arise naturally from finite fields.

Comment: I would continue by searching for cyclic/circulant Hadamard matrices and hope to find more information.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix#Circulant_Hadamard_matrices) suggests to me that the conjecture is that length 4 is the exception. But the existence of higher length examples is unknown.

Comment: I will work further on this, I believe I know the path forward. Nonetheless, the original question is thoroughly answered - kiitos.